# Can I connect to my Ubuntu session from my Windows 7 session, both installed in the same computer?

Tags: windows-7, wubi, session

I have a Windows 7 computer where I installed the Ubuntu Desktop using the Wubi installer. 
Therefore, when I start my computer I can choose between the Windows and Ubuntu sessions.

However, I was wondering if I can go from one session to the other one without shutting down any of the sessions?

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

The nearest you can do to this is to virtualise one of the operating systems inside the other using software like VirtualBox, VMWare, etc. This usually has somewhere between a slight and severe performance effect on the virtualised OS depending on what you're doing.

For example, I use XP in VMWare to handle my Adobe tools that I need for work... But I wouldn't use it for gaming.